# Может ли Apache работать одновременно с php5_module и module_wsgi?

Tags: python, apache, django, freebsd

Добрый день! Можно ли настроить апач таким образом, чтобы он обрабатывал как страницы, генерируемые php, так и django? Имеются сайты, сделанные на Drupal 7, теперь вот есть необходимость разработать сайт на Django. Я буду очень признателен за толковые ответы, которые направят мой мыслительный процесс в правильное русло.

**Обновление**

Можете ли поделиться тем, как это реализовать? Или хотя бы ссылку на материалы, где можно узнать, как все это дело настраивается? Настраивал как описано [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/), но ни к чему хорошему это не привело. Перестали работать друпаловские сайты.

Answer (score 2):

Подобные вопросы были заданы на англояычных сайтах: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333917/getting-mod-wsgireviewboard-and-mod-phpwordpress-working-on-same-servername), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333917/getting-mod-wsgireviewboard-and-mod-phpwordpress-working-on-same-servername). Там в ответах есть примеры конфигов. Если коротко, то нужно выделить для wsgi определенный путь/алиас, а не отдавать ему на обработку все запросы в иерархии сайта.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 1):

да, конечно, можно загрузить и использовать оба модуля, если под вторым имелся в виду модуль w**s**gi.

**обновление**

по приведённой ссылке, насколько я вижу, не сказано о том, что предлагаемые строки конфигурации надо вносить в отдельный *virtualhost*. вероятно, имеет смысл дополнить ваш вопрос информацией вида: есть *virtualhost* такого-то содержания, добавляю *virtualhost* такого-то содержания и от первого *virtualhost*-а в логе появились такие-то ошибки.